# PLotting multiple z-scored images in Nilearn

Tags: fmri

I have 7 z-scored images correlated to the 7 components from cerebellar cerebellar derived ICA resting state components.  Using nilearn or any other plotting packages for that matter I would like to generate a map with all the networks on it is separate colors.

Comment: What is your question? Where exactly are you stuck and what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using nilearn primarily with the plotting.stat_map    view_emotion = 'plotting.plot_stat_map(emotion_img,
                                 threshold=0.309, vmax=1,
                                 title="Emotion Network Samples"
                                 )                                                                                           
       view_emotion=view_emotion.add_markers(emotion_net_samples_array, marker_color=yellow_markers, marker_size=3)

Comment: But this is pretty ugly.  I'm trying to display 7 networks at once so showing slices of a MNI152 brain with little yellow dots doesnt really display the data well.    I found an image like this: http://www.diedrichsenlab.org/imaging/suit_connect.htm    but with markers added to mark gene sample locations on the cerebellum.